Visual aspect of an iron star
My story would be centered around the MCs finding of an iron star (I'm aware this kind of star cannot exist until the inconceivably far future, that is going to be a plot point).
I'm having trouble conceiving how an iron star might look like. The wikipedia page describes the process of iron star genesis as cold (quantum-tunneling) fusion of the light nuclei into heavier elements, followed by fission and alpha-particle emission until the stable iron nuclei mass is reached. Also, according to wikipedia, this results in "a cold sphere of iron".
So is is correct to imagine an iron star as a compact, hard and visually dull sphere of iron, with the metal in its solid state? Should it not be a metallic plasma, like described for instance in this article? If so, what would it look like? Would it give off any luminosity at all?
If it's a solid object like the wikipedia page describes, is it going to be a smooth ellipsoid? Or would it have arcs, flares or other features of a regular star?
I'm also curious if magnetohydrodynamic effects may play a role, provided the star object is rotating (which I assume it will be even if it's cold and solid).
Disclaimer: I'm writing fanfiction, so I'll ruthlessy sacrifice physical plausibility for imagery, but I'd still be interested to know with how much of the former I can get away with.

Iron stars, if they existed, would not emit light nor X-rays, nothing more than thermal infra-red. So they would look like any other, extant, non-radiating object: a brown dwarf. They could have atmospheres, too. I doubt if they could have stellar rings. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_dwarf#Spectral_and_atmospheric_properties_of_brown_dwarfs

That being said, you could certainly have a star well on its way to becoming an iron star, but not in the final dark-stage, but that might not be old enough for your purposes. Can you add a bit about what you're after (I get the impression you want something overall strange and out-of-place more than realistic).

Insofar as we understand science today it's inconceivable. The cool thing about the universe is it keeps proving humanity is only just beginning to understand science. The scientists promoting the idea that it can't be true would be the only people surprised if one was found.

@Escapeddentalpatient. I suppose I'm also fine with a dull ball of solid metal because that being a star is strange and out-of-place enough :D (I'd die for radially protruding spikes but I guess that would be pure fantasy)
That said, would you care to elaborate your comment into an answer? That may be exactly what I'm going for

"(I'd die for radially protruding spikes but I guess that would be pure fantasy)": handwave some bizarre stellar volcanism with a quantum-fluid lava extruding through holes in a crust of normal iron as the star warms after arrival. Dyson's paper was published in 1979, it's probably extremely simplified compared to reality. You're not getting big spikes in that gravity (realistically, mountain heights will be measured in millimeters), but take a large mass of material under such unusual conditions that's now far from equilibrium with its surroundings, and unexpected things might happen.

The decay to iron is a very slow process.  By the time they exist there will be effectively zero light as there won't be anything energetic enough to generate it.

I'm trying to think of a way to make it interesting/unusual - to give you options beyond the cold ball bearing. It strikes me that one way you could accomplish that would be if it were to interact with something, say another star in some way. If you were to introduce it by having it collide with a star at significant velocity perhaps.... Given the right conditions it might survive the collision (and supernova like emission of energy), and leave a trail to find it after it's escape of that gravity well. I can have a go at describing that perhaps...?

@Escapeddentalpatient. I have accepted christopher-james-huff answer as it covers this question nicely, and I have asked an additional question https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/263723/how-to-make-an-iron-star-visually-appealing with further detail for the fancy stuff

@ChristopherJamesHuff cc comment above

If you go to Dyson's paper, the iron star formation follows everything in the universe cooling to near absolute zero to allow for that quantum tunneling process. The same quantum tunneling also causes all materials to behave as liquids under such long timescales, so while they would be solid iron, they would have flowed to hydrostatic equilibrium and would be featureless ellipsoids.
Following the same reasoning, even microscopic surface defects would have flowed away, and the surface would appear polished, not dull. It might also be a superconductor with reflectivity approaching 100% at 0K. However, the current background of space is 2.7 K, which is too hot for any of these phenomena, so it would be losing reflectivity and becoming non-superconducting as it warmed up. Such an object would emit only thermal radio waves due to its cold temperature.
Artificial illumination or nearby stars would probably deliver enough energy to change the surface properties. It would also be receiving impacts from dust particles and larger objects and accreting gas. In all, its appearance would depend strongly on how long it's been here in the present universe. It could still be a quantum-mechanically weird object near 0K, or a deeply cryogenic, space-weathered iron ball with some briefly glowing impact craters and a tenuous atmosphere.
These conditions are about as different as you can possibly get from the ones in the liquid metal plasma experiments.

It seems we need a different path to an iron star than described in the Dyson paper.  It might be possible to start with the smallest neutron star (which is too small to be a black hole), and subject it to some ablative process (cosmic sandblasting, slow intersection with an anti-neutron cloud, ...) to lower the mass to the point that neutronium is not stable.  At least in a story, ultrastable iron would precipitate from the neutron/glueon soup.  The OPs question was about appearance.  With this mechanism, we have a lot of flexibility with temperature and magnetic fields.

that is, if an iron star would drop into current space, it'll heat up by the space and lose its quantum states, rendering itself an ordinary chunk of iron. If it'll happen to accrete enough non-iron on the surface, it could either collapse into a neutron star or black hole, or start fusion on iron surface thus becoming a brown dwarf.

Stars are black.
If you go by the mode of a frequency distribution you can say the Sun is blue, or a wavelength distribution would say it is red.  The color of daylight is the very definition of white, and of course, it is a yellow star in astronomical terms or to the casual observer.  But the Sun, truly, is pretty much black, as is every other star in the sky; it is simply that black objects glow red or even blue if heated up enough.  Yes, an astronomer with a spectrograph can find flaws in that black color, but I expect few such opportunities from pure iron.  We might still debate whether it is pot-and-kettle colored iron or knight-in-shining-armor colored iron, but a compact star, with iron nuclei surrounded by loose electrons, would not be in that game.  The electrons should do the absorbing, and I think therefore that a black dwarf would be black.
But what color black depends on the temperature.  If it is totally in equilibrium with the background of space, it will be that color of black, but periodically infalling matter or tidal forces could heat it up enough to get a dull cherry glow.  Basically, take a poker from the fireplace, heat or cool it to the temperature you want your star to be, and that's the color it has.

Sorry I'm not sure I understand your answer. What do you mean with "heat or cool it to the temperature you want your star to be"? The temperature of the star is not influenced by external factors, or is it?

An inert star would still take a long time to lose its heat of formation, and could still gain heat by collisions or tidal forces.  It's up to the author to decide what temperature the star is currently, and that will determine whether it has a glow detectable in visible light or other frequencies.

An iron star is by definition a black dwarf that has cooled down to the point that it no longer emits any visible light.  As for Iron being black, that is an oxidation thing caused by Earth's atmosphere over time.  Pure iron is silvery-gray.
