How to make an iron star visually appealing
Related to this question
According to the accepted answer to the question above, the most likely aspect of an iron star is that of a smooth ellipsoid of cold solid metal, with polished surface, not emitting any radiation at visible frequency.
I can work with that, but something slightly fancier would be nice.
First of all I will need a visible light source to actually see the star, and I don't want a binary system. Could cyclotron radiation from an accretion disk work to this purpose? If yes, in what manner would it illuminate the iron star?
Concerning the star body, one feature I'd really like to justify is radially protruding spikes, either distributed on the sphere (like a sea urchin), or just a corona around the equator if that makes it easier.
Barring that, I'm open to suggestions for exotic and quirky features such an object might have. Get creative! Any physically plausible mechanism is game, only as I said I'd like to avoid additional massive objects in close proximity.
EDIT: I forgot to carry over from the previous question that the iron star in my story is a regular iron star, formed in the exceedingly far future in the expected way, then transported backwards in time to the present-day universe. So it is a regular iron star in an environment that has the properties of current universe.

I mean, a sure-fire way to make anything visually appealing is a giant pair of ti....

@TheDemonLord So, make it binary?

Part of me thinks you made it look cool already: shiny, metallic, and spiky. Why not just explain it like "looks like we didn't know as much about the far future of the universe as we thought." And then shrug it off so you can have a giant spiky metal ball floating through space. Sci-fi everything else.

"Barring that, I'm open to suggestions for exotic and quirky features such an object might have. Get creative!" Except that open-ended and brainstorming questions go against this site's policy.

The surface gravity of an iron star will be most comparable to that of a neutron star or white dwarf. You're not holding big structures up against that. It's also going to be relatively small, about a hundredth the size of the sun. The tidal forces will shred pretty much anything that gets close, so actually seeing surface features will be difficult.
The surface itself will be dark, but impactors will hit at extremely high velocity. Specks of dust will make bright flashes, streams of gas will incandesce and fluoresce as they hit. The above mentioned tidal forces will shred solid objects so they impact as streaks and smears. A large enough object passing close enough to get disrupted might leave some material captured in orbit, forming a ring with material visibly impacting below as it slowly rains down.
Any gases gained as a result of the impacts will rapidly spread out into a very shallow atmosphere due to the gravity, and will freeze solid as they cool. Depending on how long it's been in the present universe, it might have a decent crust of other material.
So...say it had a close encounter with a planet sized object relatively recently (in geological terms), leaving a young disk of accreting material with a fiery line of continual impacts from dust and larger particles on the surface below it. The orbital plane isn't aligned with the star's remaining rotation, so this line creeps along the star's surface as it rotates (very slowly, having lost most of its rotation during its formation), vaporizing crust material which flows away from the impact line, condensing and freezing again. The accretion disk isn't polar, so the poles are free from this constant scouring, and vaporized materials build up there and slowly creep toward the equator under the high gravity in a process that scientists keep fighting over defining as either glaciation or tectonics.
You've got a ring of fire encircling the star from the accreting dust and gas, sparkles and streaks of larger objects impacting, and strange "weather" patterns of gas flowing from the impact zone and material much more slowly flowing into it from the poles. A bit more interesting than a giant ball bearing, and quite unlike any other objects in the universe.

@ZeissIkon it would have a mass identical to a common white dwarf, as that's what it forms from, and being composed of degenerate iron instead of carbon or oxygen, it'll be a lot denser. Surface gravity and radius will be closer to a neutron star than to anything else.

The Iron Star has an unusually strong magnetic field
And this magnetic field is causing the spikes in the surface. For example, see how iron powder behaves when near a magnet.
For the glow, the star is still hot and is slowly radiating away its energy, so even without an active fusion still ongoing, just the stored heat is still enough to make it glow.
Alternatively, you can also say that it is the strong magnetic field that is causing the heating of the star, at the tip of the spikes for example, to explain the very unique and cool property of your star :
Glowing spikes shining its otherwise dark surface.
( Please note that I no scientific background for my answer, and no idea if this would be remotely plausible in real life. This is just a cool pseudo-scientific explanation for what you want to achieve).

If iron is hot enough to glow, it's non-magnetic.  The Curie point of iron is about half the absolute temperature where it starts to emit visible amounts of visible wavelengths.  And a magnetic field will only heat the iron if the iron moves in the field and causes eddy currents (which won't happen unless there's a molten, circulating core, which I understand to be impossible in the deep time it takes for "iron stars" to evolve.

@ZeissIkon But if the iron star is cold and solid, could it be magnetized? I'm thinking about stochastic fluctuations during the star formation that may lead to spin-aligned islands to form, followed by full symmetry-breaking and spontaneous magnetization of the iron mass. Do you think that is possible given the dynamics of iron star formation?

For iron to cool from molten to below the Curie point and trap a field requires an field to be applied during the cooling -- if there's no field at the Curie transition, there'll be none when it's cold.  You could freeze in a field in a fairly thin shell while a molten core still circulates, but the final field would be relatively weak compared to that of a star or even a molten core planet.

If the author likes the magnetic spikes, and wants glow too, he can have it.  Even hard science sci-fi waves its hands to include things that do not follow from our current understandings.  For instance, whatever caused it to time-travel back billions of years, in a way we cannot currently even imagine, may have also imparted a strong magnetic charge, in a way we cannot currently even imagine.

@ZeissIkon "For iron to cool from molten to below the Curie point and trap a field requires an field to be applied during the cooling -- if there's no field at the Curie transition, there'll be none when it's cold." Isn't spontaneous magnetization due to symmetry-breaking at phase transition a thing? Anyways, my question was more that iiuc iron star form "in the cold" (from quantum tunneling) so not a regular Curie transition, different conditions, which may? allow for spontaneous magnetization (or not).

Not only will it not be able to form a solid state magnet, but even if it could, the gravity would be way more powerful than any star's magnetic field could resist.

@Nosajimiki ok, thank you

"He was turned to steel, in the great magnetic field, when he traveled time, for the saving of mankind." -- Black Sabbath

Prominences
Mickael Gumaraes is on the right track, I think: the star could have an interesting magnetic field.  If I understand it right, an iron star doesn't have to be a literal white dwarf - the iron could condense by some very slow nuclear reaction from a smaller body - but if it is big enough to be electron-degenerate matter at all, then the star will have a sea of iron cations in a sea of electrons.  The electrons should by Pauli degeneracy establish the thing's size, and the iron nuclei should be held up by electrostatic interactions.  But this is a very mobile structure, not a "solid" in the ordinary sense, so like any star, it should be able to rotate at different speeds in different layers or latitudes, and those rotational differences might lead to strong magnetic fields powering prominences at least conceptually comparable to those of the Sun.  But the strong gravity of a compact star should squash them very flat compared to the Sun's.  I have no idea if this is true, but I don't know if anyone else does either.  (Arxiv.org lists nothing about "iron star" except in the very different traditional astronomical sense, and while hit #3 for "black dwarf" gives some details, it sure as heck doesn't paint me a picture.)  You could justify some regular polygons by analogy to the polar storms of Saturn.  It might be a good time to let an artist take charge and retcon whatever pattern they come up with.

Impact craters
In its native time, there was not so much as a speck of dust or wisp of hydrogen to disturb the star's surface. But since coming back to our time, it'll have been scratched up by other objects in the general area.
It's still a star and pretty big. An entire rogue planet could have hit it and the crater would still cover a fairly small part of its surface (but perhaps launching crystalline iron debris into orbit around it?), and giving it a thin atmosphere of matter from that unfortunate planet.
Other future junk that's dragged back in time with it

NEIL: You mean reverse chronology. Like Feynman and Wheeler's notion that a positron is an electron moving backwards in time?
-- Tenet

A little bit of gas in the general area got its arrow of time flipped by the time travel, and ended up as antimatter. (Does that make sense? Don't worry about it.) So now there's a thin cloud of anti-hydrogen orbiting the iron star, blazing gamma rays as it annihilates the equally thin gas of the interstellar medium, with bright flares when a dense object like an asteroid passes through it. It might be far enough away from the iron star itself that it doesn't actually touch it (which would warm up the star's surface a lot, ruining the sweet metallic look you're going for) but still lights up the surface in blue.

Temporary Antimatter Binary
Due to [handwaving] the time travel process created an equally sized mass of anti-iron, which creates a binary system of the two "stars" co-orbiting their combined center of mass.
In-falling hydrogen gives the iron-star a tenuous H2 atmosphere, and produces matter / anti-matter annihilation in the anti-iron-star, causing it to lose mass, heat up and expand.
Eventually a planetesimal of the appropriate size falls into the anti-matter star, and there is a cinematic explosion that renders it a rapidly expanding cloud of anti-matter.
This explosion scours the side of the iron-star that is facing it, creating a highly varied topography.
Most of the cloud of anti-matter has enough velocity to escape the system entirely, but some non-trivial fraction of it forms a kind of anti-planetary disc around the iron-star, and slowly falls into it due to gas interactions.
Now your iron-star has a ring system made of anti-matter, which slowly eats away at the equator of the iron-star as the gas falls into it.
This heats up the star until it glows, provides illuminates from the anti-matter cloud itself which is constantly annihilating with the interstellar medium, and gives the iron-star a kind of strange barbell shape as the equator annihilates away.
You've probably lost of lot of the original mass from the iron-star, but now the star glows, has a ring system that also glows, and has an extremely unusual shape.
There's a visual.

I'm not sure I'm going to use your idea in the end as it would complicate matters plotwise, but I just wanted to give you kudos, it's brilliant! I love it!

Iron stars are remnants of a Kardashev II civilization
In the supposed age of Iron Stars, there will be nothing left to see
The current age of the universe is about 1.37e10 years old.  The Cold Death of the Universe will happen in about 1e12 to 1e14 years at which point all fusion fuel will be spent, and the only light left will be the hot glowing remnants of solar cores.  Iron stars will be the very very last things in the whole universe to stop emitting light which will take about 1e1500 years.  So, there is no point worrying about what an iron star will look like because there will be no way to see it, nor will there be any energy source left in the universe to support life to act as an observer to that absolute darkness.
Even Time Travel won't solve the problem, because Iron Stars will never actually form
According to current models, the universe can not possibly be stable for time periods long enough for cold iron stars to form anyway. Current models predict that within the next few billion or trillion years, that the universe will experience one of two fates: the Big Rip or the Big Crunch.
If the expansion of the universe is caused by an expansion in spacetime as some models proclaim, then in approximately 2.2e10 years, matter as we know it will become unstable and elements like iron will simply come apart turning all matter into a thin cloud of radical subatomic particles before eventually themselves coming apart and rejoining the ambient false vacuum of the universe.
However, if you interpret the expansion of the universe as as product of the Big Bang, then the universe has about another 1e8 to 1e11 years left before the expansion of the universe reverses and everything starts to collapse back down into a single super black hole.
Either way, matter will not continue to exist nearly long enough for a cold iron star to naturally form.
Hydrostatic Equilibrium further complicates the shape you want
Now let's say we handwave these problems and simply presume that matter in your universe is eternal, you will run into another problem due to Hydrostatic Equilibrium. Hydrostatic equilibrium is a state that any planet with adequate mass and density will naturally achieve.  The bigger a planet, the more spherical it will naturally become because its own gravity will make it act like a fluid at geological scales.  Since iron stars will be between about 56,000–440,000 Earth masses, their surface gravity will be so high that even small sloping hills will be highly unstable.
So not only do iron stars violate many models of astrophysics, but those models that do tell us they could exist tell us they will be extraordinarily smooth and spherical which makes your idea about them having large spikes unachievable by any known astrophysical proccess.
Therefore, spiky cold iron stars can only be artificially made.
The best way I can foresee a cold iron star existing to begin with is if an advanced civilization were to make one.  For example, if a hot solar remnant were to be exploited as a source of power and heavy metals by a Kardashev II civilization, then perhaps the heat of the solar remanent was stollen much faster than it could have naturally emitted.  If this is the case, then your iron star's surface could be extremely interesting as it could contain the ruins left behind by whatever advanced race bleed it dry of its ambient heat.  Such ruins could range from anything including large scale mines up to the remains of an entire dyson megastructure.  So it could be that your spikes you want to feature were massive unobtanium pylons that once held a dyson sphere in place and were responsible for starlifting the matter and energy out of the solar remanent back when things were still all hot and molten.
One other possibility is if the time anomaly that brought it here caused the spikes itself. It will not take such structures long to naturally collapse in on themselves, but perhaps, if it was very recently brought into our own time, then the spikes could be caused by (insert technobabble reason here) in the time anomaly and this is just what it will look like until it collapses back in on itself.

Hi, thank you for your answer. In my original question, I specified that the iron star exists in the present day universe (handwavy timey-wimey stuff), but I forgot to carry this caveat over to this question. I added that as an edit now, I'm sorry if this invalidates your answer. Feel free to change it.

@cecilian-MonicaWasMistreated In that case, my frame challenge still holds.  Even time travel can not give you a cold iron star because matter will stop existing long before the first cold iron star can form.  Even a cold iron star from the future had to have been artificially made to be able to exist before the big crunch or the big rip occurs.

This is the first time I have heard about the possibility that cold iron stars couldn't form due to the possibility of a big rip or big crunch.   I think the jury is still very much out on that one, as currently as far as we can tell the universe is flat enough that neither might occur.  Likewise our models aren't good enough to know for sure if proton decay occurs to prevent such a cold star.

@JBH He did not specify that it was naturally formed.  At the time of my answer, he just said it existed with no explanation as to how it was formed.  Even with his revised question, he states "[it] is a regular iron star, formed in the exceedingly far future in the expected way".  My answer is that all iron stars would be artificially made, therefore, this would be the regular kind of iron star formed in the only way that I would expect any iron star to be made.

@Michael Our models are not good enough to tell if the universe will last another 10 billion years or another 100 trillion years, and they can not say for certain which way the universe will end, but chaos will prevent matter from being infinite for one reason or the other.  While I would believe our models being off by enough to give matter a few thousand or even a few million times as long of a lifetime as our most generous estimates allow, 1500 orders of magnitude is such an inconceivably vast amount to be off by that it's a number beyond reckoning.

@Michael if protein decay does not occur, then it means the universe is kinetically expanding.  If that is the truth then the energy output of the universe will slowly decrease until there is only gravity left at which point the big crunch is inevitable.

@Nosajimiki ok, thank you for your input, although it seems to me that the state of the matter (concerning the theoretical possibility of natural iron star formation in the lifetime of the universe) is less clear cut than you picture. I think there's enough wiggle room there to accommodate my (fictional) story. And, I'm a she not a he ;)

@cecilian-MonicaWasMistreated Sure, a good story is certainly more important than some obscure theoretical limitation, but even if you handwave that away, an iron star is way too old, stable, and massive to have mountains tall enough to trip over, much less large sea urchin like spines.  So, even if you choose a model in which iron stars could form naturally, you will never get the kind of spines you are looking for through natural means.

Fair enough, I admitted it in the question that it was farfetched, and said I was open to alternatives

I sincerely apologize. The OP's edit came two hours after my comment.
